# Force page to zoom to 135% in Javascript using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, zooming

I'm writing a web page on high resolution screens that appear very small using bootstrap (especially IE, chrome appears to take up more of the whitespace). However when I zoom to 135% its perfect. Is there a way programmatically to set the zoom level to 135% for my web page? IE11 is the standard browser but cross compability would be nice.

Thank you

Comment: You could try something like -> `document.body.style.zoom = 1.35`

Answer (score 1):

If you try in the console what Keith suggested - `document.body.style.zoom = 1.35` it seems to be working but it feels hacky and intrusive causing noticeable fling of the page. Besides, you find 1.35 to be perfect, but it might be different for other people - that's why all the browsers have that zoom in/out feature to let users decide what best fits their needs.

The same effect can be achieved by css `zoom` property applied for high resolution screens via @media query upon page rendering:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    body {
        zoom: 1.35;
    }
}
```

But again it is commonly considered not to be the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Units like dpi, dpcm, and dppx all scale directly with resolution which would be an alternative to zoom.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution) shows the different media queries for resolution in CSS.